# hide div have same class

Tags: html, jquery, console, dropdown

I have an HTML code like this

```js
$(".data-currency="XRP").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-balance dropdown-toggle p-0 m-0" type="button" id="balance" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    
<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="USDT" data-balance="0.45229969" data-image="/images/coins/6.png">
</div>

<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="XRP" data-balance="0.00188158" data-image="/images/coins/7.png">
</div>

<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="BCH" data-balance="0.00000347" data-image="/images/coins/8.png">
</div>
```

I want hidden data-currency="XRP"  from the console but didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You need `$('[data-currency="XRP"]')`. The `.` is for selection a class, and you have 3 `"` it should either have been 2 or 4 depending on your code. Hint, next time look at your console, because it will in most cases tell you the error.

Comment: Hello. sorry.its still same. didnt hide.

Comment: @OmKador, can you check the answer I posted and confirm if it works as expected ?

Comment: not work. its says _.fn.init[etccc

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between')[3].style.visibility='hidden';

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet. You need to use `$('[data-currency="XRP"]').hide()`, not `$('.[data-currency="XRP"]').hide()`, because . selector is for class

```js
function hide() {
  $('[data-currency="XRP"]').hide()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-balance dropdown-toggle p-0 m-0" type="button" id="balance" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Some button
</button>
    
<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="USDT" data-balance="0.45229969" data-image="/images/coins/6.png">
USDT
</div>

<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="XRP" data-balance="0.00188158" data-image="/images/coins/7.png">
  XRP
</div>

<div class="currency-item mb-50 d-flex justify-content-between " data-currency="BCH" data-balance="0.00000347" data-image="/images/coins/8.png">
  BCH
</div>

<button onclick="hide()">Click to hide XRP</button>
```